# Prestashop blank theme no bootstrap

Tags: prestashop, theming

Does anyone know if there is any blank theme for prestashop? I would like to create my own theme without bootstrap though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out https://github.com/PrestaShop/community-theme-16

which just basic Bootstrap theme which you can extend. Many of work hours have been put into it to clean up the CSS, JS and TPL.

Answer (score 0):

It will be very painful to build a theme from scratch with Prestashop 1.6.

You may want to wait for Presashop 1.7 which features the [starter theme](http://build.prestashop.com/news/starter-theme-kickoff/) for that.